# xamarin Forms FreshMvvm uwp theme not correct

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have just started with Xamarin Forms and I have successfully built an IOS and UWP test app and have deployed to both an iPhone and Windows 10 Mobile phone.

However in the Windows 10 Mobile device the theme that the app uses doesn't match the default system theme.

I haven't set any theme options in the application, I have a basic FreshNavigationContainer implementation and two pages and page models.

The app looks correct based on the ios theme, but in UWP the device is set to use dark, but the app is showing light themeing at the most part, apart from when I use a table view and EntryCell, the labels are light, so hardly readable.

I'm not sure where to go from here to check what could be causing the UWP app to not respect the system default colors?

The device is using build 10.0.14965.1001 is this is any help and all updates have been applied to all current nuget packages, xamarin etc.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App.xaml`, you will have a property called `RequestedTheme`. Remove that and your app will respect user's theme choice.

Comment: Cool that was it, but the labels still are not themed correctly, do I have to set the color for them to look correct in uwp? They are showing very very pale

Comment: @JasonColey The way your app takes `Theme` from system, all the `UIElement`'s also takes their Underlying design properties from System `Accent` Colors..

Comment: Yeah well not sure whats happening then, as I do not set the label colors anywhere, yet the colors of labels are by default very very pale, almost unreadable in UWP