# How to set dark theme on Xamarin Forms UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm using on xamarin forms and on Android and iOS, and both when phone is using dark theme, it changes in order to use the same theme. But When I run app on UWP, xamarin forms work with Light theme, always. Could you tell me how to force to use dark theme? I have tried to set manually the dark theme on constructor of App.cs (UWP) as I do on native UWP apps, but it is setted but Xamarin forms continue working with Light theme. Any idea?

**Steps to reproduce it.**

- Create a MasterDetail template
- On constructor of App.cs of UWP, added the following line:
  "RequestedTheme = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationTheme.Dark;"
- Execute app and: iOS menu and status bar is dark. Android 10, menu and status bar is dark (tried on realme). Windows 10, menu is White.

Thank you

Comment: Please, share your code and what have you tried

Comment: check this possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685125/xamarin-forms-freshmvvm-uwp-theme-not-correct

Comment: Added steps to reproduce my situation.

Comment: Have you tried to remove RequestedTheme and then change system theme. Will your app react on that ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, and.... Android & iOS work correctly, but UWP continue with Light Theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set uwp theme manually, please call the following method in uwp client project.

```
public static class ThemeSelectorService
{

    public static async Task SetRequestedThemeAsync(ElementTheme Theme)
    {
        foreach (var view in CoreApplication.Views)
        {
            await view.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
                {
                    frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = Theme;
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

**Usage**

```
ThemeSelectorService.SetRequestedThemeAsync(ElementTheme.Dark);
```

Comment: Very very interesting… it is a progress. Now, I get all pages the dark theme with an exception. On a xamarin forms MasterDetailPage, the "menu" is dark theme, but, the main page and top bar is ligth theme. I tried to execute your function before the page, in the page, and after (from Other page) and it continue with light theme. The other pages of app that are contentpage without MasterDetailPage, work correctly. do you have some idea in order to force theme on masterdetailpage? Thank you

Comment: The BarBackgroundColor of masterdetail page is not theme color, we could not change it with above code. but you you could edit it  manually,  you could find it in App.xaml file.

Comment: Yes, the bar is the little of problems, I'm going to create other project in order to recognize what is exact the problem. I have masterdetailpage and how detail is a tabbedPage and it is showed with light theme, while the master (menu) and other pages are with dark theme.

Comment: The problem with my tabbedpage and masterdetailpage was my computer…. the HDD was corrupted and stop working… I had to install a new hdd, fresh installation of Windows and VS, and voila, your solution work perfectly. Thank you!!!